# App Engine, appcfg and saving uploading credentials

Tags: python, google-app-engine

On Linux, it seems that appcfg.py saves credentials when I use it to upload a new version of my application. However, this doesn't seem to happen OSX, and the password is asked every time.

On Linux, I have local installation. On OSX, I have used binary installer.

Is it possible to do something for OSX, so that it would save me the effort of retyping password all the time?

More info: Found zero sited .appcfg_cookies in my home folder. Obviously it is not saving credentials there, though trying.

Comment: Strange, I use both OS X and Linux and appcfg saves my credentials on both machines.  It seems like on your OS X appcfg is not generating a `~/.appcfg_cookies` file.  Can you confirm that this file doesn't exist?  How are you running appcfg on OS X?

Comment: I have been using OSX binary bundle and launcher to set up paths for me. appcfg.py is global system with installation in /usr/bin (or was it /usr/local/bin).

Comment: I'll check if that file is having issues. In any case this happens on two OSX computers, so it must be an systematic error in how I do the things.

Comment: Removing ~/appcfg_cookies DIDN'T do any good.. filing a bug report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

1) Updating Google Appengine to version 1.4.2 via launcher (I might have hit 1.4.x bug?)

2) Deleting cookie file

it looks like cookie file started working again.

It should have content like:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
    # http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
    # This is a generated file!  Do not edit.

appengine.google.com    FALSE....
```

Comment: where can we find the cookie file??

Comment: it is .appcfg_cookies under your home folder: e.g /home/ubuntu if you logged in as ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

You can use the OAuth 2.0 feature of `appcfg` to avoid the need to enter your login and password. It is documented for [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Passwordless_Login_with_OAuth2), [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth) and [Go](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth).

Instead of using your login and password to authenticate you, you will proceed once through an OAuth 2.0 grant flow in your web browser. The results of that grant will be cached for future pushes.

To use this feature, just add one option to your `appcfg` command: `--oauth2`. For Java, it looks like this:

```
$  appcfg.sh --oauth2 update ./web
```

Comment: For python, in the directory where app.yaml resides: appcfg.py --oauth2 update .

Comment: The --oauth2 suggestion is great and works just like @jenny-tong describes. But this solution doesn't work if you need an unattended website/app update using appcfg.py (or other lang equivalents). For example, using a build system like Travis or Shippable.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [launcher](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html) for OSX, it allows to store the credentials in the OS Keychain.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Python module keyring - http://bitbucket.org/kang/python-keyring-lib

Supports Linux (Gnome,KDE), Win32 and OSX keychain backends. Worked great for me.