# Have dev_appserver.py and appcfg.py remember your password

Tags: google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App Engine, appcfg and saving uploading credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292103/app-engine-appcfg-and-saving-uploading-credentials)

I have recently activated [two-step verification](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&topic=1056286) on my Google account. This has me generating application specific passwords for all applications where I log in with my Google account, including dev_appserver.py, remote_api_shell.py, appcfg.py and other Google App Engine command line tools.

In all other applications, the generated password can be remembered, but I have not found out how to make dev_appserver.py remember my password. It is a hassle to generate a new one on every deploy.

I am on a Mac, so I can use the Google App Engine Launcher for the dev server and deployment, but I prefer to use the make system we have set up in our project. In addition, there is no standalone application for running the remote API shell.

Any hints on how to make dev_appserver/appcfg remember your password? It is possible at all?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292103/app-engine-appcfg-and-saving-uploading-credentials

Comment: Thanks alot! Didn't find that one when I searched earlier